# How would you create a JSON file based on different cols of your database (PostgreSQL/SQLAlchemy) in Flask to use it in your JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, flask, sqlalchemy

Would this happen in views.py? And if so, how would the file be created?

For example in app/models.py, some of the columns include:

```
 class Company(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
     permalink = db.Column(db.String(255))
     name = db.Column(db.String(255))
     homepage_url = db.Column(db.String(255))
     description = db.Column(db.Text)
     founded_on_day = db.Column(db.Integer)
     founded_on_month = db.Column(db.Integer)
     founded_on_year = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I want to create a JSON file with specific fields that I'd select for 'company' objects and access it in my html/Javascript code such as:

```
  d3.json("data.json", function (data) {
```

And then just selected specific fields from there to render.

How would the file be created based on the database's information.

Answer (score 1):

The views are used to perform actions and/or serve data as a response to a HTTP method sent to the web server. If you want a specific JSON file to be created, that's more suitable to be done from a script called regularly (with cron for example).

On the other hand, I don't think you need to create a JSON file at all. It would be more suitable for you to create a view that is serving the URL used as the first argument to `d3.json()`. You could have something like this:

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/_get_companies')
def get_companies_json():
    companies = {}
    for c in session.query(Company).all():
        companies[c.id] = {
            'name': c.name,
            'homepage_url': c.homepage_url,
        }

    return jsonify(companies)
```

Of course the contents of the returned JSON object is dependent on what you are trying to do, but you should get the idea.

Then in you JS file use:

```
d3.json('http://domain.com/_get_companies', function(data) {
    // Process your data
}
```